# Flutter error while using place_picker: ^0.9.15

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am working with flutter to get autocomplete google map but, i am getting error while hot reload.

I have used flutter dev instruction and coppied same code and and used same dependencies.

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/google_maps_flutter.dart:17:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/google_maps_flutter.dart:20:1: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

export 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart'
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/google_maps_flutter.dart:18:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface-1.0.4/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_google_maps_flutter.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_google_maps_flutter.dart';
^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/src/controller.dart:7:7: Error: Type 'GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform' not found.
final GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform _googleMapsFlutterPlatform =
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/src/controller.dart:16:5: Error: Type 'CameraPosition' not found.
CameraPosition initialCameraPosition,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/src/controller.dart:29:5: Error: Type 'CameraPosition' not found.
CameraPosition initialCameraPosition,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/src/controller.dart:113:31: Error: Type 'MarkerUpdates' not found.
Future _updateMarkers(MarkerUpdates markerUpdates) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.5.33/lib/src/controller.dart:125:32: Error: Type 'PolygonUpdates' not found.
Future _updatePolygons(PolygonUpdates polygonUpdates) {

Code

```
void showPlacePicker() async {
 LocationResult result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlacePicker("AIzaSyDNpXzdfghcvbrfthgqQKh2oAHFau5_fCc")));

 // Handle the result in your way
 print(result);
 }
```

dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  place_picker: ^0.9.15
```

Please help me to slove this problem.
Thanks.